# Properly licensing a plugin that uses Apache 2.0 licensed code

Tags: plugin-development, licensing, plugin-repository

Am developing a plugin that I would like to submit to the WordPress.org repo. It's dependent on Apache License 2.0 code, so I know I should license my plugin with GPLv3 - it's allowed.

So, how do I properly license my plugin? Obviously I should include *License: GPLv3* in my plugin's header, but it feels like there's more I should do. What else should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From WordPress point of view — not much, beyond plugin's header (and even there) it is hardly policed.

From licensing point of view you obviously need to accommodate requirements of both licenses accordingly. At least — make clear that your combined work is under GPLv3 and which parts of it are based on Apache License 2.0 code.

GPL site has instructions on [how to apply terms](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html#howto), although recommendation to have it done in *every* source file is widely disregarded in practice.